# Why Does This MySQL Query Not Work On The Live Server

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that works when I troubleshoot this within my code on my local pc, it works perfectly but the moment I put this up on the live server the query fails for some reason, I think, but I'm not sure, that this boils down to the date fields somehow but honestly I have no idea why it's failing on the server. I have tried the sql functions Date, date_to_string and my dates are in the format '2019-03-08' please assist, my query is as per below.

```
select posted_ads.id, posted_ads.title, 
       posted_ads.description, posted_ads.price, 
       posted_ads.datePosted, 
       posted_ads.adCategory, 
       posted_ads.adSuspended, posted_ads.suspensionEmailSent, 
       posted_ads.adSuspensionReason, posted_ads_images.id, posted_ads_images.imageName, 
       posted_ads_images.type, posted_ads_images.adID
from posted_ads inner join
     posted_ads_images
     on posted_ads.id = posted_ads_images.adID
where title like '%mechanic%' and
     posted_ads.adExpired = 0 and 
     posted_ads.datePosted between '2018-12-09' and '2019-03-09'
group by posted_ads.id
limit 6 offset 6
```

Comment: Define does not work? Do you get a error or are you not getting the expected results?

Comment: You are using a `GROUP BY` on `posted_ads.id` but using other columns without aggregation on `SELECT`. This could be the issue. (SQL mode `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` could be the difference between servers)

Comment: @SebastianBrosch MySQL supports a optional feature which is called functionally dependent of the SQL 1999+ standard see [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) which allows writting those queries how MySQL detects [functionally dependent](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html)

Comment: @RaymondNijland it is either an error "input string was not in in a correct format" 
or I get no results, this seems to have something to do with the dates cause when I remove them results come through

Comment: @SebastianBrosch can you please give me a more detailed explanation as I'm not an advanced mysql user